# bash command with shell scripting doesn't work

Tags: shell, startup, kannel

when I start ubuntu server 14 I must start bearerbox and smsbox.

The commands are:

```
bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
```

and

```
smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
```

The first command block the shell soo for start smartbox I need open new shell.
(The second command also block the second shell too)

**I've tried to use:**

```
bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf &
smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf &
```

But bearerbox and smsbox **doesn't work**.

**I've also tried to create a shell script like:**

```
#!/bin/sh
bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
```

And start it with ./start.sh but **doesn't work**.

Someone can help me please?

Comment: I do not know kannel. Does starting it with nohup helps (`nohup bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf > /tmp/bearartrace.log 2>&1 &`) ?

Comment: if i use 

nohup bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf &

nohup bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf &

In the terminal It worsk, but if I create a script with only this 2 rows doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't enough information to debug, well, _anything_.

Answer (score 1):

Try a script running with bash and starting with :

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf > /tmp/bearer.out 2>&1 &
nohup smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf > /tmp/smsbox.out 2>&1 &
```

In /tmp you should find files that might explain possible problems.
When those files don't get created/show nothing, you might want to debug with echo:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup echo bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf > /tmp/bearer.out 2>&1 &
nohup echo smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf > /tmp/smsbox.out 2>&1 &
```

When all is clear, redirect to /dev/null:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup smsbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

(and remove the /tmp files)